# Noob question: How do I bind the hoizontal/vertical axis to 4 touch buttons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code in question, it is used to move a 3D cube up/down/left/right.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 Vec; 
    void Start()
    {

    }
 
    void Update()
    {

        Vec = transform.localPosition;
        Vec.x += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 20;
        Vec.y += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * 20;
        transform.localPosition = Vec;
    }
}
```

I've tried setting up Input Manager, but I gave up due to my lack of patience.
Plus, I don't know how to bind a button to an action.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing directly built-in for giving you the current pressed state of a `UnityEngine.UI.Button` or other objects.

But you can implement this using [`IPointerXYHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) interfaces like e.g.

```
public class PressedState : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnerHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHander, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] Button _button;

    public bool isPressed { get; private set; }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // not needed only required for handling exit
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        isPressed = false;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        isPressed = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        isPressed = false;
    }
}
```

*On UI this works out of the box, if your buttons are 3D colliders you need a `PhysicsRaycaster` on your Camera, if they are 2D colliders a `PhyicsRaycaster2D`.*

Then have this attached to all four buttons and handle them like e.g.

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] PressedState up;
    [SerializeField] PressedState down;
    [SerializeField] PressedState left;
    [SerializeField] PressedState right;
 
    void Update()
    {
        var vertical = 0;
        if(up.isPressed) vertical += 1f;
        if(down.isPressed) vertical -= 1f;
        var horizontal = 0;
        if(right.isPressed) horizontal += 1f;
        if(left.isPressed) horizontal -= 1f;

        var Vec = transform.localPosition;
        Vec.x += horizontal * Time.deltaTime * 20;
        Vec.y += vertical * Time.deltaTime * 20;
        transform.localPosition = Vec;
    }
}
```

To be exact `GetAxis` applies some sort of smoothing which you could optionally add using e.g. [`Mathf.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothDamp.html) if you really need it

---

Side note: In general you usually want to avoid faster diagonal movement so I would probably rather use

```
var movement = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(horizontal, vertical), 1f) * Time.deltaTime * 20;
transform.localPosition += movement;
```

Comment: Thanks my friend.
I'm currently experiencing problems trying to implement this code in my original code (might be my small head!). Hopefully I get around or else I'll need one of those really basic tutorials.